# Keras Autoencoder Bug - Grainy Output

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to set up an Autoencoder to "denoise" images. After training, I noticed that the images my autoencoder was predicting from the test set turn out completely grainy. In fact, it's nothing but grains.

Just, to rule out any set-up problems, I decided to replicate Keras tutorial on Autoencoding MNIST images exactly as it's written on their website, line-by-line.

https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

To my surprise, this exact issue is occurring. Please see my screenshot attached.

I'm really puzzled because I followed Keras's tutorial exactly as it's written. I've reproduced the error on 2 different computers and both locally and on the cloud. The tutorial was written in 2016. The only thing that comes to mind is something in Keras's API was changed and the layers don't function the same way they did in 2016.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D183.png)

Code to reproduce-

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 32  # 32 floats -> compression of factor 24.5, assuming the input is 784 floats

# this is our input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)

# create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

# encode and decode some digits
# note that we take them from the *test* set
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)

# use Matplotlib (don't ask)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10  # how many digits we will display
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post code as text and not as an image.

Comment: The image is not to show the code really but the actual picture output of the network.

Comment: I realize that; and considering the code isn't even relevant to the question, it makes it even more helpful to post relevant code.  I got momentarily confused with the code and realized it's not relevant to the question.